# Como retornar palavras mais comuns de um texto com PHP?

Tags: php

Eu gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma de retornar as ocorrências mais frequentes de substrings em uma string contendo texto. Exemplo:

```
$texto = "Hoje nós vamos falar de PHP. PHP é uma linguagem criada no ano de ...";
```

E o output:

```
array(
    "PHP" => 2
    "de" => 2
    //...
);
```

A idéia é que seja retornado um `array` com as palavras mais usadas em determinada *string*.

Eu atualmente estou usando a função [`substr_count()`](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr-count.php), mas o problema é que ela só funciona se você já passa uma palavra a ser verificada, ou seja, eu precisaria saber as palavras do texto para verificar uma por uma.

Existe alguma outra forma de se fazer isto?

Comment: Qual a melhor solução? Fica a pergunta...

Comment: Pois é, vou tentar montar um teste de performance assim que tiver tempo para avaliar o melhor resultado, mas todas as soluções são muito interessantes.

Comment: No PHP toda string é considerada um array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
print_r(array_count_values(str_word_count($texto, 1, "óé")));
```

Resultado:

```
Array ( 
   [Hoje] => 1 
   [nós] => 1 
   [vamos] => 1 
   [falar] => 1 
   [de] => 2 
   [PHP] => 2 
   [uma] => 1 
   [linguagem] => 1 
   [criada] => 1 
   [no] => 1 
   [é] => 1
   [ano] => 1 
)
```

Para entender como `array_count_values` funciona veja o [manual do php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php).

***Edição***

### Uma solução mais inteligente (independente do idioma)

Com a solução anterior é necessário especificar todo o set de caracteres especiais do utf-8 (assim como foi feito com o `ó` e o `é`).

A seguir uma solução, mas complicada, porém, elimina o problema do set de caracteres especiais.

```
$text = str_replace(".","", "Hoje nós vamos falar de PHP. PHP é uma linguagem criada no ano de ...");
$namePattern = '/[\s,:?!]+/u';
$wordsArray = preg_split($namePattern, $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$wordsArray2 = array_count_values($wordsArray);
print_r($wordsArray2);
```

Nessa solução utilizo expressões regulares para quebrar as palavras e logo em seguida, utilizo o `array_count_values` para contar as palavras. O resultado é:

```
Array 
( 
  [Hoje] => 1 
  [nós] => 1 
  [vamos] => 1 
  [falar] => 1 
  [de] => 2 
  [PHP] => 2 
  [é] => 1 
  [uma] => 1 
  [linguagem] => 1 
  [criada] => 1 
  [no] => 1 
  [ano] => 1 
)
```

Essa solução também atende a necessidade, porém, os pontos devem ser eliminados antes do split das palavras, caso contrário aparecerá no resultado palavras com `.` e palavras sem o `.`.Por exemplo:

```
  ...
  [PHP.] => 1 
  [PHP] => 1 
  ...
```

Contar palavras nunca é uma tarefa tão simples assim. E necessário conhecer bem a `string`que deseja contar as palavras antes de aplicar uma solução definitiva.

Comment: Para que serve a string `"óé"` no final?

Comment: @Kazzkiq pra não quebrar "nós" em 2 palavras, nem desconsiderar o "é". Você teria que por todos os caracteres não ASCII nesta solução para não quebrar palavras acentuadas em várias. Esta solução é boa quando você quer ignorar pontos, vírgulas, números, e tudo o mais que não for palavra, mas tem que montar toda a acentuação. A do @Sergio já é boa se você quiser contar varias strings, independente de serem palavras ou números ( `1987`, `bem-vindo`, etc... )

Comment: @Kazzkiq na nova solução aplicada, ainda temos o problema da limpeza do texto, porém, considero essa nova forma de se implementar um pouco mais inteligente e simples do iterar todas as palavras.

Answer (score 4):

A minha maneira "artesanal" seria:

```
$texto = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";

$palavras = explode(' ', $texto);
echo count($palavras); // 91
$ocorrencias = array();

for($i = 0; $i<count($palavras); $i++){
    $palavra = $palavras[$i];
    $ocorrencias[$palavra]++;
}

arsort($ocorrencias);
var_dump($ocorrencias);
```

Resultado:

```
array(69) { 
    ["the"]=> int(6) 
    ["Lorem"]=> int(4) 
    ["of"]=> int(4) 
    ["Ipsum"]=> int(3) 
    ["and"]=> int(3) 
    ["a"]=> int(2) 
    // etc
```

A vantagem desta alternativa é que só preciso de separar por espaços em branco.

Pode também juntar uma linha assim, antes do `explode()`:

```
$texto = preg_replace('/[,\.?!;]*/', '', $texto);
```

para limpar virgulas e pontos, etc.. Dependendo do que procura.

Answer (score 2):

## Minha solução

Essa soluçao é um pouco mais robusta, ele separa cada palavra e a trata "minuciosamente", depois de tratada e aprovada, ela passa para uma nova array que depois é organizada pelo número de ocorrências.

```
<?php
$texto = "Hoje nós vamos falar de PHP! mas o que é PHP?? 
PHP é uma linguagem criada no ano de ...";

/* Separar cada palavra por espaços (raw, sem filtro) */
$palavras_raw = explode(" ", $texto);

// Array de caracteres para serem removidos
$ignorar = 
[".", ",", "!", ";", ":", "(", ")", "{", "}", "[", "]", "<", ">",
"?", "|", "\\", "/"];

// Array para as palavras tratadas.
$palavrasTratadas = array();

/* Criar uma nova array de palavras, agora tratadas */
$palavras_raw_count = count($palavras_raw);
for ($i=0;$i<$palavras_raw_count;++$i) {
    $palavraAtual = $palavras_raw[$i];
    $palavraAtual = trim($palavraAtual);
    if (!empty($palavraAtual)) {
        $palavraTratada = str_replace($ignorar, "", $palavraAtual);
        $palavraTratada = strtolower($palavraTratada);
        if (!empty($palavraTratada)) {
            $palavrasTratadas[$palavraTratada]++;
        }
    }
}

// Organizar pela ordem de mais ocorrências.
arsort($palavrasTratadas);

// DEBUG
print_r($palavrasTratadas);
```

Ele separa cada palavra pelo critério espaços e remove os caracteres especiais a partir da array `$ignorar` depois ele trata todas as palavras para prevenir erros / resultados inesperados e passa para a array `$palavrasTratadas`, vale notar que ele **NÃO DIFERENCIA** maiusculas das minusculas, pois alguem pode começar a frase com a maiuscula Hoje e depois utilizar hoje no resto do texto, porém a função de passar as palavras para minusculas do PHP é feita para o inglês, então ela não converte Á para á, por exemplo.